# PostgreSQL trigger update average and count when new value in column is added

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE mark (
EID serial,
PID integer,
SID integer,
score integer DEFAULT 5 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_EID PRIMARY KEY(EID),
CONSTRAINT "FK_personne_ID"
FOREIGN KEY (PID)
REFERENCES personne (PID)
ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
CONSTRAINT "FK_serie_ID"
FOREIGN KEY (SID)
REFERENCES serie (SID)
ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

My trigger : when a new row/value is inserted in the column "score", updates the average score and the total count of scores:
I'm not sure if I should implement a function ahead or start with the trigger directly :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FunctionUpdateScore(float) RETURNS integer AS 
'BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(score) AS nb_score, AVG(score) AS ag_score 
FROM mark;
END;'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

--trigger
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TriggerUpdateScore
AFTER INSERT 
ON mark
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE FunctionUpdateScore();
UPDATE nb_score
SET nb_score= nb_score+ 1
END;
```

Comment: What you need to do is read [Create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) first.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, read many blogs and posts, but my trigger still does not work :

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TriggerUpdateScore
AFTER INSERT 
ON evaluation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE serie s 
    SET noteMoyenne = (NoteMoyenne*nbNotes + :new.note) / (nbNotes + 1), nbNotes = nbNotes + 1
 WHERE :new.sid = s.sid;
END;

Comment: Read the links and you would know what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Properly escape your trigger body. Use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)
2. Remove the float argument from your function
3. Actually perform the update in your function
4. Update the correct table (you are updating the `nb_score` table in your example which does not have a trigger on it, therefore it will not fire off the trigger)
5. Specify a relationship between `mark` and `nb_score`. As of now the trigger function below updates all `nb_score` rows, not just the one that is related to the inserted row in `mark`.;
6. Your function return type must be trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FunctionUpdateScore() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
 UPDATE nb_score
    SET 
        nb_score=COUNT(score),
        ag_score=AVG(score)
    FROM mark;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER TriggerUpdateScore
AFTER INSERT ON mark FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE FunctionUpdateScore();
```